# How to update converted leads using DataLoader?

Tags: data-loader, leads, spring16

I need to populate one new custom field on Lead object in all the lead records for reporting purposes.

**What I tried:**

The first problem I encountered was with leads already converted. The error message looked like:

> cannot reference a converted lead

In Spring'16, Salesforce released new permissions that allow users to update fields on converted leads ([Release Notes](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/spring16/release-notes/rn_sales_leads_edit_converted_leads.htm)).

So I activated these permissions on my custom Admin profile (Modify All in all objects). Then I tried to update a converted Lead using Developer Console (query, edit a few and click Save Rows) and it worked.

As I have to update 80k+ Leads, usign the UI/Console is discarded.

So I tried with *DataLoader*. I get rid off of my first error message but a new one appeared:

> first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_OR_READONLY, insufficient access rights on object id: []

Then I tried *Apex Script* and *Batch Apex*; same error.

**Question:**

Why I'm getting a INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_OR_READONLY error if I'm logged in as a System Administrator?

I'm missing something at this point? Maybe some other permission, or something related with teams?

I read some workarounds on the internet (delete records and insert them again) but I don´t really like them.

More info:

- I'm still unable to update leads using the Salesforce Classic UI. When I click *Edit*, I land on *ViewConvertedLead* standard page.
- OWD Sharing Setting for Leads is set to *Private*

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: What version of dataLoader are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across the same error and managed to get it to work by reducing the batch size in Data Loader down to 1 and the Use Bulk API option checked, not ideal for updating 80k+ records but that's the only way I found.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I tried with batch size set to 1 and it worked (independently of Use Bulk API check). Now I have to wait 10 hours more or less to get this finished... what a pain... Thanks again.